# Problem with cell style in pivot mode Ag-grid

Tags: pivot, ag-grid

I have a problem with cell style in pivot mode: all mode such as row group and simple grid work well, but when I change to pivot mode just row style works and the cell style is not working.

See the link below

https://plnkr.co/edit/8AFyzB5XvqlQg51Q

I use this code in colDef

```
 cellStyle: {color: 'red', 'background-color': 'green'}
```

and getRowStyle  in gridOptions

```
var gridOptions = {
    getRowStyle : function(params) {
        if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
            return { background: 'blue' };
        }
   }
}
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

well coldef in AG-grid refers a simple column but the moment you perform grouping and pivoting its no longer a simple column it becomes a groupcolumn and if its autogroupcolomn then ag grid generates it. so if you want to apply styles to row group in grouped or pivot mode then you have to define it like this.

```
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
    width: 180,
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        //check that the autogroup is built using country column and then color every odd cell 
        if(params.node.field ==='country' && params.node.rowIndex% 2 === 1){
        return {color: 'red', 'background-color': 'white'}
               }
             }
          },
```

check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3Lfxnuy/) to see the working demo